# Sqlalchemy and Flask API won't return column and value from a database

Tags: python, sqlite, api, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm running a flask web framework tied in to a sqlite databade. I'm having an issue returning a query that includes both the column name and the value of that column. I'm including the relevant code below.

```
import threading
import time
import KeySys
import serial
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

e = create_engine('sqlite:///lockdb.db')
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('LockSwitch')

class Keystat_Meta(Resource):
    def get(self):
        #Connect to databse
        conn = e.connect()
        #Perform query and return JSON data
        query = conn.execute('select * from LockStat')
        return {'KeyStat': [query.cursor.fetchall()]} # I've tried keys() all() items(column, value) and various different queries.

api.add_resource(Keystat_Meta, '/keystat')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? `query` should be a dictionary according to the [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage). Try printing `query.items()` to see if you're getting results.

Comment: Thank you for helping, when I do query.cursor.fetchall() I get the values without the column names, if I do query.keys() I get all the column names but no values. if I do query.items() I get the error 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: You may refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277548/return-field-name-and-value-from-sqlalchemy-result

Comment: @ichbinblau That documentation is for sqlalchemy .9 and is deprecated. I'm running the latest sqlalchemy 1.1. I tried it anyways but no it doesn't work column_description is no longer a query option.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this, it took me a day of pounding at it but I found a solution

return {'KeyStat': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}